# How to create narrow collision detection between a player's melee weapon and an enemy

Tags: python, pygame

Whenever the player is in range of a particular enemy, then the player can swing their sword and cause damage to that enemy that is in front of them.  I have this code here that demonstrates the system I have in place now:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
     if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
         if event.button == 1: #Event called when left click
             for enemy in enemies: #An array that holds instances of enemies 
                 if (math.sqrt( ( (enemy.x - x) **2) + ( (enemy.y - y)**2) ) < (100+reachBonus) ): #Using distance forumla to calculate player x and y values in corresondance to an enemies x and y position 
                     enemy.health -= woodenSword.damageAmount #subtracts the enemies health by the amount of damage that the woodenSword does
```

The problem with this system is that I'm only checking if the player is within a specific range, so technically it will work in a circular range around the enemy.  This would work for something like an explosion, but since I am working on a fighting system and the player has to be looking directly at an enemy, this wouldn't really work.

As possible approach I consider raytracing. I am used to Unreal Engine, where you can send out a line trace, which is basically an invisible line that will return True if it has hit something directly. This would be an option if I cast several rays in front of the player and see if it collides with enemy, but I did not find how to do in pygame and it feels like not very effective solution as I may need to send multiple rays to start with. Also that is common for 3d space - maybe 2d game I have can go with basic math instead.

What can I do to fix my mechanic so it will only work if the player is looking straight at the enemy, and not just in range?

Comment: Your title is completely off the topic based on your question. If you want to get an answer please edit your question and fix it. You probably are looking for [raycasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_casting) not collision detection.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I'm new to this kind of thing.  I've edited the title to accurately reflect my situation.

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385257/can-someone-please-explain-to-me-how-i-could-improve-in-this-question)

Comment: Can't you simply check the angle between the player's gaze vector and the player to enemy direction vector? E. g. something like `V = enemy.position - player.position; if (length(V) <= player.attack_range) and (angle(V, player.gaze) <= some_small_angle) do_damage()`

Comment: I'm not sure how I would get the player's gaze vector.  Something that also confuses me is that you have an "angle" function.  What would that do?

Comment: If you don't know the player's gaze direction, then in what direction did you want to "send out a line trace", or how could you possibly know if the player is looking straight at the enemy or not? As for the angle function, that's a pseudo-code, meaning "an angle between the two vectors". Plenty of vector libraries out there that will calculate that for you. Or write your own angle function, it's no rocket science. `pygame.math.Vector2.dot` function calculates dot product of two vectors, it's trivial to get the cosine of the angle from that.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are attempting to re-invent the wheel for features that already exist within pygame.

You are attempting to determine whether or not the sword is making contact with a mob.

This is already covered by pygame's collision detection features.

Instead of calculating the proximity of your character to each mob, instead generate a sprite on mouse click for the area of the sword attack.  Then test for a collision between the mobs and the weapon sprite.  If there is a collision, do the damage calculation.

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html

With regard to raycasting, this would be useful if you are attempting to calculate an endpoint for some sort of a laser or rope or something else where you are constructing a solid "thing" between a start and end point and need to know the end point before generating the "thing" on screen.  For a typical melee attack it isn't necessary.

Comment: I was under the impression pygame's collision detection feature only works for drawn rects/circles etc.  I am loading in png's I have made in photoshop. If I am mistaken and this feature does work for custom images, how would I generate a sprite and use that to check if it has hit a mob?

Comment: Your sprite has a hitbox rect.  That hitbox can be differently sized that the image itself.  You could even put to gether a collection of hitboxes to make more complex shapes - but this gets needlessly complicated.  The limitation of this option is that your image and collision area may not match.  As such the collision area may be larger or smaller than the image.  This has been an issue is gaming since the dawn of time.  I recommend really diving into the documentation and reviewing some sample code - perhaps from a project you like that is out on github.

Comment: @NoIdea - the collision detection can use bitmasks in addition to `rect`s.  This gives you pixel-perfect collisions.